# Hide/remove "Last" label/icon in views pager

Tags: views, 9

I don't want my user to click the "Last" label on the views pager, but I can't find a way to remove this "Last" label even I leave the "Last page link text" field empty, I don't want to use the mini pager, so in the full pager, how can we remove the "Last" label/icon ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can override [pager.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21pager.html.twig/10) in your theme, removing the section that adds the 'last' link:

```
{% if items.last %}
  <li class="pager__item pager__item--last">
    <a href="{{ items.last.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to last page'|t }}"{{ items.last.attributes|without('href', 'title') }}>
      <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Last page'|t }}</span>
      <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.last.text|default('Last »'|t) }}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
```